# JavaScript Random Number Generation: Unique 500 Integers in Space 10^6: Getting Collisions

Tags: javascript, random

Below is a very simple example of Random Integer generation in JS where I'm not "stretching the limits" by any means.

I'm only generating 500 unique random integers from a very large space, 10^6.

And yet, if you keep clicking the button, you'll occasionally see 499 or 498 unique ones out of the 500. It doesn't happen extremely often, but it happens maybe on every 10th or 15th click. Why is that? My space is 1 million. I don't expect to get collisions in a sample of 500 with the frequency of every 10th or 20th click.

**To test, keep clicking the button and watch the console**.

```js
function run() {
  var nums = new Set();

  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    nums.add(randomInteger10to6th());
  }

  console.clear();
  console.log('Random 10^6 Unique Integer set: ' + nums.size);
}

function randomInteger10to6th() {
   return Math.round(Math.random() * Math.pow(10,6))
}
```

```html
<button id="run" onclick="run();">Run 500 Random Integers, Space: 10^6</button>
```

Comment: https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: Have you heard of the birthday paradox? 500 random numbers amongst 1000000 is a roughly 10% chance of collision (according to some random calculator I googled for birthday paradox)

Comment: The joys of the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) and JavaScript's pseudo-random number generator! You may want to check if the number you generate already exists in your set, and if so, attempt to keep generating a number until it doesn't already exist in the set

Comment: @ChrisForrence: what do you mean by "JavaScript's pseudo-random number generator"? there's many implementations. Above that, do you expect different results from `crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint16Array(1))` ? Math is math, and Math.random (these days) is uniform and has a huge period.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The probability of you seeing all unique numbers when you pick 500 randoms from 1-1e6 can be calculated as follows:
1e6/1e6 * 999,999/1e6 * 999,998/1e6 * ... * 999,501/1e6

This comes out to about 0.88

Which means more than 10% of the time, you're going to have at least one duplicate in your list of 500 randoms.

You can validate this behavior in the snippet below for 100 experiments:

```js
function run() {
  var nums = new Set();
  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    nums.add(randomInteger10to6th());
  }
  return nums;
}

function randomInteger10to6th() {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 6))
}

// perform 100 experiments and see how many have duplicates
var uniques = 0, collisions = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var nums = run();
  if (nums.size === 500) uniques++;
  else collisions++;
}

console.log('Runs that generated unique numbers', uniques);
console.log('Runs that resulted in collisions', collisions);
```

Answer (score 1):

"Random" means just that: it's random. Every value in the range has the same probability of being chosen, regardless of what's been chosen before. So even if it picked the number 5, for instance, it still has the same chance of picking 5 again as it does of picking any other number. You shouldn't expect random numbers to avoid duplicates -- if they did, they wouldn't be random :)

Comment: That is not answering the question.

Comment: That's a good point, thanks. But I need the RNG to provide sufficient uniqueness for me.

Comment: @trincot How isn't it? The question was "why am I getting duplicate random numbers?" and my answer was "because random numbers are just as likely to produce duplicates as any other number".

Comment: @geneb. I'd suggest, then, that you populate an array with the integer range you need, then shuffle it. This way the order of the numbers chosen will be random, but as you iterate through the array, you're guaranteed not to have duplicates since the array contains no duplicates.

Comment: Seems like a fine answer to me. As a solution, you can run a while loop instead of the for loop until your set has reached the desired size

Comment: @lucas Yeah, I was going to suggest that alternatively, he could just keep a list of already-picked numbers and, on collisions, re-roll until there's no collision. The problem there is that it's potentially unbounded. While it's unlikely to actually run infinitely, the more numbers that are picked, the less efficient it becomes (as the chance of collision increases while the already-picked list grows).

Comment: @IceMetalPunk isn't a list of already-picked numbers what a Set is for in the first place?

Comment: @IceMetalPunk the question is not *why* there are duplicates, but why it happens so frequently. Your answer does not explain why that is. Just saying that random means there could be duplicates is not explaining why it happens surprisingly (to the OP) that *often*. See the other answer that *does* give an explanation.

Comment: @lucas Yes; I was agreeing with you, just pointing out that such a method would introduce potentially unbounded behavior, while the shuffled-list approach wouldn't. (With the trade-off being more memory usage, but there's always a trade-off.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are generating a relatively small number of random numbers from a large sample you should be able to regenerate a new number on collision. Adding random nums until you get to 500 will result in a few extra calls to the random generator, but it will guarantee 500 unique numbers:

```js
function run() {
    var nums = new Set();
  
    while (nums.size < 500){
       nums.add(randomInteger10to6th());
     }
  
    console.clear();
    console.log('Random 10^6 Unique Integer set: ' + nums.size);
  }
  
function randomInteger10to6th() {
   return Math.round(Math.random() * Math.pow(10,6))
}
```

```html
<button id="run" onclick="run();">Run 500 Random Integers, Space: 10^6</button>
```

Comment: it would be (much) faster to take 650 and keep the first 500 in the set, no comparing, and your odds of failing are astronomical, and can be guarded against cheaply.

Comment: Why the duplicate check? Isn't the point of the Set that it doesn't allow dupes?

Comment: @dandavis that's interesting. If you take 650 are you guaranteed to have 500 unique?

Comment: Like i said, pretty much, and a simple `IF SIZE < 500 REPEAT` covers your lotto winnings for much cheaper than 499 compares each run...

Comment: Thanks @lucas — fixed. That was pretty boneheaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simple arrays instead of `Set()`. First, create the array of 500 indexes then fill it.

```js
function run() {
      /* first create an array with 500 slots, then fill it with 
         undefined ( fill() without args is undefined ). For the 
         last step map through 500 slots of undefined and overwrite 
         it with a random number */
      return new Array(500).fill().map(x => Math.round(Math.random() * Math.pow(10,6)))
}

console.log(run().length)
```

```html
<button id="run" onclick="run();">Run 500 Random Integers, Space: 10^6</button>
```

And if you want to remove the duplicates then you can simply filter them out an recalculate.

```js
function run() {
  // same like the upper function but with a duplicates filter
  let arrayWithNumbers = new Array(500).fill().map(x => Math.round(Math.random() * Math.pow(10,6))).filter((item, idx, self) => self.indexOf(item) == idx)
  // run again if array less than 500
  if(arrayWithNumbers.length !== 500) { 
   run() 
  }

  return arrayWithNumbers
}

console.log(run().length)
```

```html
<button id="run" onclick="run();">Run 500 Random Integers, Space: 10^6</button>
```